# Configure Module in Shared Module from Root

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a shared module that imports and configures another module.

What I would like to do is hide the dependency of the shared module from the root module, but allow the root module to configure it through configuring the shared module.  In example:

SharedModule.ts:

```
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    //want to configure this from root module without importing into root module
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      provide: ConfigLoader,
      useFactory: (configFactory),
      deps: [HttpClient]
    })
  ],
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  exports: [MyComponent],
  providers: [HttpClient]
})
export class SharedModule{ }
```

AppModule.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule, //Want to configure ConfigModule from here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It seems this isn't possible by implementing ModuleWithProviders (static forRoot), since it doesn't expose imports.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
export class SampleModule {
  static forRoot(config: CustomConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    // User config get logged here
    console.log(config);
    return {
      ngModule: SampleModule,
      providers: [SampleService, {provide: 'config', useValue: config}]
    };
  }
}
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

  foo: any;

  constructor(@Inject('config') private config:any) {
```

Comment: That's configuring CustomConfig, not ConfigModule.